# Attempting to implement redirect()->route but get an empty page

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

So this should be really simple, but I'm struggling with it for some reason.  I have a helper (`SiteTools.php`) with a function called `clearCart()`.  Its only job is to unset a cart session variable, then redirect to an order summary page to announce to the user that there is nothing in their cart.

What I've tried is several variations of return `redirect()->route('ordersummary')`.  Out of desperation, I tried a fallback to `header('Location','/ordersummary')`.  Nothing but an empty page.

Here is my `web.php` in which i define both the routes:

```php
// shows the user the order summary page
Route::get('/ordersummary', array('as' =>'ordersummary','uses'=>'OrderCheckoutController@index'));
// clear out the shopping cart completely (mostly just for dev purposes)
Route::get('/clearcart', 'OrderCheckoutController@clearCart');
```

Here is my `sitetools.php` file in which the `clearCart()` function resides:

```php
namespace App\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\RedirectResponse;
use App\Customers;

class SiteTools {
    public function clearCart() {
        unset($_SESSION['cart']);
        return redirect()->route('/ordersummary');
    }

     // yadda yadda yadda...
}
```

Here is the code from `OrderCheckoutController.php` where I'm attempting to implement this:

```php
use App\Helpers\SiteTools;
// yadda yadda yadda...

    public function clearCart() {
        $site_tools = new SiteTools;
        $site_tools->clearCart();
    }
```

My expected result is that when I go to `mysite.com/clearcart` that it will unset the session variable (which it does) then redirect to `mysite.com/ordersummary` (which it does not)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using a different method for routing between the two.  If possible, change the `ordersummary` route to match the same usage as the `clearcart` route (which we know works).  Try this:

```
Route::get('ordersummary', 'OrderCheckoutController@index'); // Try without the '/' as well
```

Also, on the controller after unsetting, try using the facade:

```
Redirect::to(url("ordersummary"));
```

Comment: So the reason I'm doing it this way is mainly so that in the browser URL line you see /ordersummary and not /clearcart after the operation is done.  I think it would look weird to show an order summary page with the url of mysite.com/clearcart in the URL line.  On the facade... which file should I include to access that Redirect object?

Comment: No that's fine - I'm just saying try the Route as I have written it above, not with the array and 'as' and all that.  Clean and simple.  It will still go to ordersummary, but hopefully not show a blank page.  I didn't mean use the same word (clearcart), just the same use of the method :)   On redirect, it is Laravel standard, try `\Redirect::`

Answer (score 0):

i advise you to use laravel facades for session manipilating 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session.

for deleting an item from session use `request()->session()->forget('cart')`.
or `Session::forget('cart');`

for routes use named routes it'll ease your pain like this:

```
Route::get('/ordersummary', array('as' =>'ordersummary','uses'=>'OrderCheckoutController@index'))->name('ordersummary');
```

then call it like this: `return redirect(route('ordersummary'));`

Comment: Ok, so i tried it this way, and still no joy.  I"m using Laravel 5.7.21, don't know if that makes a difference... but the error I get trying to use the return redirect() you outlined was:  "Route [ordersummary] not defined."  (left panel) and " throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");" (right panel when I get the "whoops" page)   I changed the Route statement to what you have exactly, so not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong here...   I restarted the server after I made the change - still no joy...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, boys and girls... behold.  So the final answer to this was to first, in my web.php (where all my defined routes reside) I defined the route as follows:

```
Route::get('/ordersummary', array('as' =>'ordersummary','uses'=>'OrderCheckoutController@index'));
```

Notice that using this syntax, you do not use the ()->name('...') method.  If you do, then when you do a route:list you'll notice that your route name will be doubled.  For example:

```
Route::get('/ordersummary', array('as' =>'ordersummary','uses'=>'OrderCheckoutController@index'))->name('ordersummary');
```

will yield a route name of 'ordersummaryordersummary'...

The second and most important thing I was doing (which I can't believe nobody caught) was that in the controller calling the clearCart() method, I wasn't returning anything - I was merely calling the method as such:

```php
    public function clearCart() {
        $site_tools = new SiteTools;
        $site_tools->clearCart();
    }
```

but I was not actually returning anything - as a result, when I was doing it right, I would get nothing but an empty screen.  When I changed it to this...

```php
    public function clearCart() {
        $site_tools = new SiteTools;
        return $site_tools->clearCart();
    }
```

Everything worked exactly as intended.